# Uncaught ExitStatus with AR.js on server

Tags: javascript, three.js, augmented-reality, ar.js

I'm using https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js and three.js for an AR  project, in local everything works fine but when I deploy on server (platform.sh), I got this error after accepting camera :

```
Uncaught ExitStatus ar.js:19
message: "Program terminated with exit(0)"
name: "ExitStatus"
status:    0
__proto__: Error at https://xxx.eu.platform.sh/assets/js/ar.js:19:2247
   constructor: ƒ ExitStatus(status)
     arguments:    null
     caller:    null
     length:    1
     name:    "ExitStatus"
     prototype: Error at https://xxx.eu.platform.sh/assets/js/ar.js:19:2247
    __proto__: ƒ ()
    [[FunctionLocation]]:  ar.js:19
    [[Scopes]]: Scopes[1]
   stack: "Error↵    at https://xxx.eu.platform.sh/assets/js/ar.js:19:2247"
```

Here is the build I'm using https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/blob/master/three.js/build/ar.js
How to fix that ?

PS: This happen on latest versions of Chrome, Safari and Firefox

Comment: In my case, this happened when I accidentally loaded the js twice.